# Build error in Xcode. Problem with linking

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I build game from unity

Then open **.workspace** file

I try to build on iPhone

There are Facebook and firebase analytics in my project and google ads and audience network.

My error

> ld: warning: arm64 function not 4-byte aligned: _unwind_tester from /Users/razrabotcik/Documents/Builds/TestBuil5/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(unwind_test_arm64.o)
>    ld: Linking globals named 'fbad_Cocos2DGetGLViewController': symbol multiply defined! for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I try to search `fbad_Cocos2DGetGLViewController` in project but this file doesn't exist.
How fix this error

Answer (score -1):

you should delete   -ObjC in OtherLink.  Can solve this problem